# 32 bit barrel shifter in verilog has no input

Tags: verilog

I'm creating a 32 bit shifter with multiple muxes, here is the code:

```
module shifter_32bit(a, b, out);
    input [31:0] a;
    input [4:0] b;
    output wire [31:0] out;

    genvar gv_i;
    genvar gv_j;
    genvar step;

    generate
        for (gv_i = 0; gv_i < 5; gv_i = gv_i+1) begin: level
            for(gv_j = 0; gv_j < 32; gv_j = gv_j+1) begin: bit
                wire mux_wire;
                if(gv_i == 0) begin
                    if (gv_j - (1<<gv_i) < 0) begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], a[gv_i], 1'b0, mux_wire);
                    end else begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], a[gv_i], a[gv_i - (1<<gv_i)], mux_wire);
                    end
                end else if(gv_i == 4) begin
                    if (gv_j - (1<<gv_i) < 0) begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], a[gv_i], 1'b0, out[gv_j]);
                    end else begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], a[gv_i], a[gv_i - (1<<gv_i)], out[gv_j]);
                    end
                end else begin
                    if (gv_j - (1<<gv_i) < 0) begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], level[gv_i-1].bit[gv_j].mux_wire, 1'b0, mux_wire);
                    end else begin
                        mux mux_s(b[gv_i], level[gv_i-1].bit[gv_j].mux_wire, level[gv_i-1].bit[gv_j - (1<<gv_i)].mux_wire, mux_wire);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    endgenerate

endmodule //   a[31:0], out[31:0]
```

And here is the test bench:

```
module shifter_test;
    reg [31:0] a = 32'd4;
    reg [4:0] step = 5'd4;
    wire [31:0] out;

    shifter_32bit shifter(a,step,out);

    initial
        begin
        #50 a = 32'd4;
        #50 a = 32'd8;
        #50;
        end
endmodule // mux_4way_test;
```

But in simulation i noticed that input a in the shifter has no value, in modelsim it displayed as '32'hzzzzzzzz'. Really have no clue what's going on.

Comment: To solution is to look at the waveform and trace where your signals get lost. We can't help you as we have no idea what 'mux' does.

Comment: Sorry, mux is a 2 to 1 multiplexer. I checked the waveform in the shifter, it seems that a and b are not connected because they have no value. But in the testbench i definitly connected them.

Comment: how did you noticed that the inputs are 'z'? This is usually an initial value of a net, which the input is. Might be a compilation issue in your case. Did you really compile the testbench?

Comment: Did you type `vsim shifter_32bit` instead of `vsim shifter_test`?

Comment: I used GUI to choose the file so that should not be the problem.